# Example of a commutative ring which is not a subring of a commutative ring where every non-invertible element is a zero-divisor

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I don't remember whether there was a special name for a commutative ring where every non-invertible element is a zero-divisor. And I also forgot the different ways in which a non-invertible element can be nasty. One obvious way to be nasty is to be a zero-divisor. So now

> I'm looking for an example of a commutative ring which is not a subring of a commutative ring where every non-invertible element is a zero-divisor.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/42647/rings-in-which-every-non-unit-is-a-zero-divisor.

Comment: Thanks for the link. So instead of "every non-invertible element is a zero-divisor", I could say "every regular element is a unit". Sweet, short and positive...

Comment: When every right-regular element is a unit, one also finds it called a **right coHopfian ring**.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every commutative ring $R$ is a subring of its [total ring of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_quotient_ring), which is precisely the "natural" version of $R$ where every element is either a unit or a zero-divisor. Specifically, it is the localization of $R$ at the multiplicative subset $S\subset R$ consisting of the non-zero-divisors.

Thus, there is no such commutative ring $R$ with the property you're looking for.